# Classification of strange critical point in the plane

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

What type is the critical point $(0, 0)$ for the following system?

\begin{align}
&x' = y\, ,\\
&y' = -x^2 - x^3\, .
\end{align}

The critical points for this system are:

- $(-1, 0)$, a center; and
- $(0, 0)$.

The Jacobian for this problem is

$$\pmatrix{0&1\cr -3\,x^2-2\,x&0\cr }\, ,$$

and in $(0,0)$ is

$$\pmatrix{0&1\cr 0&0\cr }\, .$$

That  is not-normal and has only one eigenvector.

The following is the phase portrait for the system, with a contour plot for the conserved quantity,

$$V(x, y) = \frac{(3x + 4)x^3}{12} + \frac{y^2}{2}\, ,$$

and a trajectory for the value of $0$, the one that cross the $(0, 0)$ critical point.

[image]

#### Perturbed critical point

If we perturb the system as

\begin{align}
&x' = y\, ,\\
&y' = -(x^2 - \epsilon^2) (1 + x)\, ,
\end{align}

We have the following critical points:

- $(-1, 0)$, a center;
- $(-\epsilon, 0)$, a saddle point; and
- $(\epsilon, 0)$, a center.

So, the original point seems to be a merging of these last two points.

Comment: [This](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/East_Tennesee_State_University/Book%3A_Differential_Equations_for_Engineers_(Lebl)_Cintron_Copy/8%3A_Nonlinear_Equations/8.2%3A_Stability_and_classiﬁcation_of_isolated_critical_points) talks about the topic without exactly answering your question. I will look for better.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor, thanks. I will take a read. Should I add to the question that the Jacobian has only one eigenvector on the critical point?

Comment: Yes, more detail is almost always good.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor: That link is not relevant, since it only covers the standard stuff for a nonsingular Jacobian matrix (plus explaining why a linear center says nothing about the nonlinear situation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of equilibrium point is called a **cusp**. It's defined by the phase portrait having two so-called *hyperbolic sectors* separated by two *separatrices*; see Section 2.11 in Perko's *Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems*, for example. The prototypical example of a system with a cusp at the origin is $\dot x=y$, $\dot y=x^2$:

[image: Cusp point]

(As an aside, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4044831/saddle-node-behaviour-of-planar-systems) for an example that at first glance looks like a cusp but turns out to be something else.)